# Look up a state given an area code

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to do this? I just want to get "New York" or "NY" when I put in "212", preferably without connecting to some service, and "New Jersey" or "NJ" when I put in "201".

Does Android have an API for this? I'm not looking for the location of the user's phone, but rather a lookup table or something to just get the location of a given area code.

Comment: There are commercial databases available; you're looking for a NPA NXX database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my function. It is in here: https://github.com/asantosca/areacode

Comment: Did you write that just for me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could either look at a database, just [google a list](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&safe=off&es_sm=93&q=area+code+to+state+list&oq=area+code+to+state+list&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l4.4316.4576.0.4767.4.4.0.0.0.0.102.304.3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..0.4.303.XcrhdYtc5Tc) or just hardcode it into your application. I would recommend one of the latter two, rather than adding a dependency into your application.